# What does -> mean in Python function definitions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, function-definition

I've recently noticed something interesting when looking at [Python 3.3 grammar specification](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/grammar.html):

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' suite
```

The optional 'arrow' block was absent in Python 2 and I couldn't find any information regarding its meaning in Python 3. It turns out this is correct Python and it's accepted by the interpreter:

```
def f(x) -> 123:
    return x
```

I thought that this might be some kind of a precondition syntax, but:

- I cannot test `x` here, as it is still undefined,
- No matter what I put after the arrow (e.g. `2 < 1`), it doesn't affect the function behavior.

Could anyone familiar with this syntax style explain it?

Comment: If you find this in any code nowadays, it's probably a type hint for a static type checker like mypy. https://www.mypy-lang.org/

Answer (score 713, accepted):

It's a [function annotation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

In more detail, Python 2.x has docstrings, which allow you to attach a metadata string to various types of object. This is amazingly handy, so Python 3 extends the feature by allowing you to attach metadata to functions describing their parameters and return values.

There's no preconceived use case, but the PEP suggests several. One very handy one is to allow you to annotate parameters with their expected types; it would then be easy to write a decorator that verifies the annotations or coerces the arguments to the right type. Another is to allow parameter-specific documentation instead of encoding it into the docstring.

Comment: And the information is available as a `.__annotations__` attribute.

Comment: Wow, I missed quite a broad area of knowledge - not only return value annotations, but also parameter annotations. Thank you very much :).

Comment: @Krotton Can't blame you for missing it, it's practically unused. I only ever met a single library using them, and it's quite obscure.

Comment: And the `__annotations__` attribute is a dictionary. The key `return` is the one used to retrieve the value after the arrow.

Comment: @delnan -- probably the reason that it's mostly unused is because most python libraries still aim to be compatible with python2.x.  As python3.x begins to become more standard, we might see more of these things popping up here and there...

Comment: In python 3.5 they added "type hinting", as described in PEP484 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: Would love to see examples

Comment: @user395760, could you please add a link to the library that uses `function annotations` extensively!

Comment: To specify parameter types, you put them after the variable name like so: `def foo(bar: int)`, in this case specifying that bar is an int.

Comment: @Anu The huggingface does so. There's actually a lot of really great OOP code in here I wasn't familiar with in Python: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/d9a81fc0c5d8339357a42435009a5be3a190b305/src/transformers/hf_argparser.py#L134

Comment: One thing that I don't understand is here https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/#accessing-function-annotations, the given example is `def foo(a: 'x', b: 5 + 6, c: list) -> max(2, 9):`. Why would a function annotation have an actual expression? Instead of say, a string or a type, which can help a coder know what the parameter does or accepts? What is its usecase of having expressions here?

Answer (score 623):

These are function annotations covered in [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). Specifically, the `->` marks the return function annotation.

Examples:

```
def kinetic_energy(m:'in KG', v:'in M/S')->'Joules': 
    return 1/2*m*v**2
 
>>> kinetic_energy.__annotations__
{'return': 'Joules', 'v': 'in M/S', 'm': 'in KG'}
```

Annotations are dictionaries, so you can do this:

```
>>> '{:,} {}'.format(kinetic_energy(12,30),
      kinetic_energy.__annotations__['return'])
'5,400.0 Joules'
```

You can also have a python data structure rather than just a string:

```
rd={'type':float,'units':'Joules',
    'docstring':'Given mass and velocity returns kinetic energy in Joules'}
def f()->rd:
    pass

>>> f.__annotations__['return']['type']
<class 'float'>
>>> f.__annotations__['return']['units']
'Joules'
>>> f.__annotations__['return']['docstring']
'Given mass and velocity returns kinetic energy in Joules'
```

Or, you can use function attributes to validate called values:

```
def validate(func, locals):
    for var, test in func.__annotations__.items():
        value = locals[var]
        try: 
            pr=test.__name__+': '+test.__docstring__
        except AttributeError:
            pr=test.__name__   
        msg = '{}=={}; Test: {}'.format(var, value, pr)
        assert test(value), msg

def between(lo, hi):
    def _between(x):
            return lo <= x <= hi
    _between.__docstring__='must be between {} and {}'.format(lo,hi)       
    return _between

def f(x: between(3,10), y:lambda _y: isinstance(_y,int)):
    validate(f, locals())
    print(x,y)
```

Prints

```
>>> f(2,2) 
AssertionError: x==2; Test: _between: must be between 3 and 10
>>> f(3,2.1)
AssertionError: y==2.1; Test: <lambda>
```

Comment: This is extremely useful, thank you! Although, as I remember the underscore `_` allows you to call the last function/variable but I'm wondering what `lambda` in this case as `_y` doing? Also, can `_between` be replaced with just `_`?

Comment: In both cases, the `_` is a shortcut to *I kinda mean the same name as [that] but I don't want to figure out if the namespace allows me to use the same name or it would be confusing.* With `between` and the inner function `_between` it is not needed but confusing if the same name. These could be the same names. With the lambda, you have the name (key of a dict) of the lambda function and the name of the argument. Again, similar but confusing if the same name.

Comment: As someone too young to have used annotations for something other than type-checking, I think this answer is fascinating.

Answer (score 314):

In the following code:

```
def f(x) -> int:
    return int(x)
```

the `-> int` just tells that `f()` returns an integer (but it doesn't force the function to return an integer). It is called a *return annotation*, and can be accessed as `f.__annotations__['return']`.

Python also supports parameter annotations:

```
def f(x: float) -> int:
    return int(x)
```

`: float` tells people who read the program (and some third-party libraries/programs, e. g. pylint) that `x` should be a `float`. It is accessed as `f.__annotations__['x']`, and doesn't have any meaning by itself. See the documentation for more information:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Answer (score 133):

As other answers have stated, the `->` symbol is used as part of function annotations. In more recent versions of Python `>= 3.5`, though, it has a *defined* meaning.

[PEP 3107 -- Function Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) described the specification, defining the grammar changes, the existence of `func.__annotations__` in which they are stored and, the fact that it's use case is still open.

In Python `3.5` though, [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) attaches a single meaning to this: `->` is used to indicate the type that the function returns. It also seems like this will be enforced in future versions as described in [What about existing uses of annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#what-about-existing-uses-of-annotations):

> The fastest conceivable scheme would introduce silent deprecation of non-type-hint annotations in 3.6, full deprecation in 3.7, and *declare type hints as the only allowed use of annotations in Python 3.8.*

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

This hasn't been actually implemented as of `3.6` as far as I can tell so it might get bumped to future versions.

According to this, the example you've supplied:

```
def f(x) -> 123:
    return x
```

will be forbidden in the future (and in current versions will be confusing), it would need to be changed to:

```
def f(x) -> int:
    return x
```

for it to effectively describe that function `f` returns an object of type `int`.

The annotations are not used in any way by Python itself, it pretty much populates and ignores them. It's up to 3rd party libraries to work with them.

Comment: Nice answer. Just out of curiosity, do you use them in your code?

Comment: AWS seems to be using them: https://github.com/awslabs/fraud-detection-using-machine-learning/blob/master/source/env_setup.py

Answer (score 15):

This means the type of result the function returns, but it can be `None`.

It is widespread in modern libraries oriented on Python 3.x.

For example, it there is in code of library **pandas-profiling** in many places for example:

```
def get_description(self) -> dict:

def get_rejected_variables(self, threshold: float = 0.9) -> list:

def to_file(self, output_file: Path or str, silent: bool = True) -> None:
"""Write the report to a file.
```

Comment: "This means the type of result the function returns, but it can be None." It can be None or any other type.

Answer (score 11):

```
def f(x) -> 123:
    return x
```

My summary:

1. Simply `->` is introduced to get developers to optionally specify the return type of the function. See [Python Enhancement Proposal 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)
2. This is an indication of how things may develop in future as Python is adopted extensively - an indication towards strong typing - this is my personal observation.
3. You can specify types for arguments as well. Specifying return type of the functions and arguments will help in reducing logical errors and improving code enhancements.
4. You can have expressions as return type (for both at function and parameter level) and the result of the expressions can be accessed via **annotations** object's 'return' attribute. **annotations** will be empty for the expression/return value for lambda inline functions.

Answer (score 11):

```
def f(x) -> str:
return x+4

print(f(45))
```

Will give the result : **49**.

Or in other words '-> str' has NO effect on return type:

```
print(f(45).__class__)

<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 8):

`def function(arg)->123:`

It's simply a return type, **integer** in this case doesn't matter which number you write.

like **Java** :

```
public int function(int args){...}
```

But for Python (how [Jim Fasarakis Hilliard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193772/6157415) said)   **the return type it's just an hint**, so it's suggest the return but allow anyway to return other type like a string..

Answer (score 7):

**->** is introduced in python3.

In simpler words, the content after the **->** denotes the return type of the function.
The return type is optional.

Comment: How does the guidance in this answer differ from the guidance in the previous answers already posted?

Comment: The return type might still be different, the annotation is like an expression that explains the return value of the function, but if for example we put str after '->' but we return an int, python would not give any error.

Answer (score 4):

It's just telling the user what it expects or return the value

`funcname.__annotations__` will print the details

like

```
def function(name:str ,age:int) -> "printing the personal details ":
    print(f"name is {name} age is {age}")

function("test",20)
print(function.__annotations__)
```

***The Output***

```
name is test age is 20
{'name': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>, 'return': 'printing the personal details '}
```

even when you return the values it display nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [PEP3107](https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/) specification. These are function annotations. Python 2.x has docstrings. Similarly, Python 3 introduced the use of -> as function annotations. Python uses these while generating documentation.