# Decorator with function annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

In PEP 3107 and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379780/455276) it is implied that Python3K function annotations and decorators fit hand and glove -- that I should be able to write a decorator that works with function attributes.

I cannot figure how to make them work as I expect however.

Consider:

```
def verbose(lcls):
    def wrap(f):
        print('inside wrap')
        def wf(*args):
            print('inside wf')
            print('lcls in wf:',lcls)
            print('locals in wf:',locals())
            print('wf annotations:',wf.__annotations__)
            print('xYx annotations:',xXy.__annotations__)
            r=f(*args)
            print('after f(*args)')
            return r
        return wf
    return wrap           

@verbose(locals())    
def xXy(x: 'x in x\'s', y: 'y in Y\'s') -> ('x times y','in x and y units'):
    print('locals in xXy:',locals())
    return x*y

xy=xXy(10,3)    
print(xy)
```

Prints:

```
inside wrap
inside wf
lcls in wf: {'xXy': <function verbose.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.wf at 0x109767ef0>, '__doc__': None, 'verbose': <function verbose at 0x109767050>, '__cached__': None, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins'>, '__package__': None, '__file__': '/private/var/folders/gx/gqtmx9mn7b75pk1gfy0m9w3w0000gp/T/Cleanup At Startup/test-383453350.857.txt', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10959ac10>, '__name__': '__main__'} 
locals in wf: {'f': <function xXy at 0x109767e60>, 'args': (10, 3), 'lcls': {'xXy': <function verbose.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.wf at 0x109767ef0>, '__doc__': None, 'verbose': <function verbose at 0x109767050>, '__cached__': None, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins'>, '__package__': None, '__file__': '/private/var/folders/gx/gqtmx9mn7b75pk1gfy0m9w3w0000gp/T/Cleanup At Startup/test-383453350.857.txt', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10959ac10>, '__name__': '__main__'}, 'wf': <function verbose.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.wf at 0x109767ef0>}
wf annotations: {}
xYx annotations: {}
locals in xXy: {'y': 3, 'x': 10}
after f(*args)
30
```

What that group of lines shows me is that I cannot see how to access the value of x and y in xXy in the decorator or the function attributes of xXy.

What I would *like* to do is 1) have a function with annotations as specified in PEP 3107, 2) be able to have a decorator that can access the function annotations and the values the function is called with without just being a clone of of xXy's function signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New in version 3.3,[`inspect.signature()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)would allow you get the information you want in a function decorator. Here's an example of using it to print the argument names and values passed on each call to a decorated function as well as access the associated annotations:

```
import functools
import inspect

def verbose(wrapped):
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)  # optional - make wrapper look like wrapped
    def wrapper(*args):
        print('inside wrapper:')
        fsig = inspect.signature(wrapped)
        parameters = ', '.join('{}={}'.format(*pair)
                               for pair in zip(fsig.parameters, args))
        print('  wrapped call to {}({})'.format(wrapped.__name__, parameters))
        for parameter in fsig.parameters.values():
            print("  {} param's annotation: {!r}".format(parameter.name,
                                                         parameter.annotation))
        result = wrapped(*args)
        print('  returning {!r} with annotation: {!r}'.format(result,
                                                         fsig.return_annotation))
        return result
    return wrapper

@verbose
def xXy(x: 'x in X\'s', y: 'y in Y\'s') -> ('x times y','in X and Y units'):
    return x*y

xy = xXy(10, 3)
print('xXy(10, 3) -> {!r}'.format(xy))
```

Output:

```
inside wrapper:
  wrapped call to xXy(x=10, y=3)
  x param's annotation: "x in X's"
  y param's annotation: "y in Y's"
  returning 30 with annotation: ('x times y', 'in X and Y units')
xXy(10, 3) -> 30
```

Comment: Excellent! I was playing with inspect, but I had not quite figured it out yet.

Comment: Just a fyi: `inspect.signature` was added in Py3.3, so works for the asker. It's not available in Py 3.0-3.2.

Comment: It only took BDFL [6 years to accept](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/#acceptance) and 1 day to add! :-)

Comment: I love 3.3, it's full of awesome stuff (my personal favourite being `yield from`).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [`functools.wraps()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
def verbose(lcls):
    def wrap(f):
        print('inside wrap')
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wf(*args):
            print('inside wf')
            print('lcls in wf:',lcls)
            print('locals in wf:',locals())
            print('wf annotations:',wf.__annotations__)
            print('xYx annotations:',xXy.__annotations__)
            r=f(*args)
            print('after f(*args)')
            return r
        return wf
    return wrap
```

This is a simple decorator that ensures that a wrapper function carries the attributes of the function it wraps.

Comment: That solves the lack of attributes (thanks), but is the value of 'x' and 'y' available in 'wf'? Could I print inside of 'wf' x=10 and y=3?

Comment: @thewolf Yeah, just extract those values from `args` or change the signature to accept those specific arguments.

Comment: That does not retain the parameter annotations. Try inspect.getfullargspec(X.f) or inspect.getfullargspec(X().f) where f is decorated with verbose.