# SyntaxError:Invalid Syntax on python import JWT

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to import the package JWT into Python 2.7 and I am getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Comment: You have a Python 3 version of this package installed.

Comment: @vaultah I don't see how that  directly answers the problem with an import statement.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks that was the problem, needed to install Pyjwt package to get it work thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was trying install jwt for Python 3 when I needed the package Pyjwt for Python 2.7

Answer (score 8):

The logical thing to install jwt on Python 2 is:

```
pip install jwt
```

Which lead to the error.

The correct install which worked on my side is:

```
pip install PyJWT
```

and it worked.