# python : function type parameter

Tags: python, types, parameters

Is there a way to enforce the type of a variable in a python function ? Or at least, give an indication of what it should be ?
I already saw things like :

```
var -> int
```

But I don't know the name of that syntax, nor its use.

Thanks

Comment: there is not, python is not strictly typed

Comment: so what does this syntax means ? a:var->int ? And  I know it is not stricly typed but my question is : or, is there a way to give an indication?

Comment: and I don't know why someone would feel the urge to downvote the question.. I am just looking for the vocabulary involved to be able to search the PEP for advice.

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Comment: @bipII from PEP.484 -> [PEP 3107 introduced syntax for function annotations, but the semantics were deliberately left undefined. There has now been enough 3rd party usage for static type analysis that the community would benefit from a standard vocabulary and baseline tools within the standard library.
This PEP introduces a provisional module to provide these standard definitions and tools, along with some conventions for situations where annotations are not available.] [...] so : no it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called `Type Hints`, has been introduced in Python 3.5 and is described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

See also PEP 484: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Example:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

Note that this will not *enforce* the type.

From the PEP:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual `__annotations__` attribute, no type checking happens at runtime. Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily.

Comment: To enforce the type, just add ad an assertion in your function `assert type(name) is str`