# What does '->' mean in a function declaration in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-declaration

Recently, I have come across this `->` in Python 3 when studying function declarations. What does this do and mean? I have never seen such a declaration other than in a Javascript function declaration up until now.

```
def f(self, s: 'str') -> 'bool':
    pass
```

Comment: Function `f` will return a boolean value. This enhances readability and makes it easy to debug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is annotation for type of return value of function.

> def sum() -> expression:
>
> That is, the parameter list can now be followed by a literal ->
>   and a Python expression. Like the annotations for parameters, this
>   expression will be evaluated when the function definition is executed.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Answer (score 3):

According to [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) related to typings.

> This is the python *typing* feature, which let you specify the **return** type of functions in python