# Understanding: "def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:" on leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, class

I am working through some problems on leetcode and i dont understand the same code that they have written.  For example, why is there an arrow pointing to int ( -> int:)?  Also i dont understand what the TreeNode is being used for.  Is it just to validate the inputs?

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Called function annotations, have a read of this page.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

or

[What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

> In more detail, Python 2.x has docstrings, which allow you to attach a
>   metadata string to various types of object. This is amazingly handy,
>   so Python 3 extends the feature by allowing you to attach metadata to
>   functions describing their parameters and return values.
>
> There's no preconceived use case, but the PEP suggests several. One
>   very handy one is to allow you to annotate parameters with their
>   expected types; it would then be easy to write a decorator that
>   verifies the annotations or coerces the arguments to the right type.
>   Another is to allow parameter-specific documentation instead of
>   encoding it into the docstring.

user: Katriel

The `TreeNode` itself is part of the data structure of a binary tree, I do not know the specific leetcode question being mentioned but essentially the tree is made up of many `TreeNodes` that reference other `TreeNodes` through the variables `self.left` and `left.right`, the names are used to emulate what a visual binary tree would traditionally look like. They are just defining the Node so that you can understand what class to expect in answering the question.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-data-structure/

Comment: This should probably just be flagged as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @glibdud Thank you