# Why do I get syntax error on function definition python?

Tags: python, macos, syntax-error

When I try to define this function on python (Wing101 IDE Mac OS) it says that there is a syntax error from the first ":" to the end of bool: 
I'm just trying to specify the return type after the arrow. I don't understand what's wrong, can someone help?

```
def destroymatrix(text: str) -> bool:
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: In case you are using an older version than 3.5, type hints (which is what the syntax error points at) are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess id say the python you're using is not python 3.x

See this quesition:

[What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)