# What function does this syntax perform in python

Tags: python

Please explain the syntax in the arguments of the longestCommonPrefix function.
This function takes a list of strings as inputs.

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments and the `->` describe the type of the function.

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    pass
```

So it takes one argument, `strs` which is a list of strings (`List[str]`).
Then it returns a string (`str`).

Comment: To add to this answer, the `self` argument means this function is a non-static member function of some class