# Please explain -> Vector: in python

Tags: python, coding-style

How to explain -> Vector: in Python

what does this mean in python

```
from typing import List
Vector = List[float]

def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]

# typechecks; a list of floats qualifies as a Vector.
new_vector = scale(2.0, [1.0, -4.2, 5.4])
```

Comment: You're creating an alias for `List[Float]` called `Vector` for further type-hints. The rest is vanilla type-hinting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Function Annotations: [PEP 3107 -- Function Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).
Also look at this post: [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)