# What does the next method represent? def method(self, a : dict) -> list:

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I have the next questions in the below code line. Please help.

```
def method(self, a : dict) -> list:
```

- 1st question: what does it mean to declare **a: dict**?
- 2nd question: What does that arrow (-> list) means/indicates/represents?

To be honest I just have an idea about the first thing (a: dict), but I need the complete picture about how that way of writing that kind of python method works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions

Answer (score 3):

So these are type hints.

`a : dict` is saying that `a` should be of type `dict`

and  `-> list` is saying the function will return the type `list`

The documentation for this can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Answer (score 2):

1. `a : dict` means the argument 'a' for the function is of dictionary type.
2. `-> list' means that this function will return a list variable.

Comment: Thanks both of you!
Kind regards