# Strange class declaration I found in Python

Tags: python, class

So I was trying to do a bit of programming problems on LeetCode and I saw a method of class declaration that I'm not so familiar with. This was how it was:

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
```

And what I'm used to is something more like:

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s):
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/%E2%80%A6) that has no runtime significance (in the absence of other libraries like Pydantic), but allows for some static type checking.

In this case, it simply means that the type of `s` is a string, and that the method returns an `int`