# How to interpret this strange Python routine coding format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across a strange format of Python code about routine. What is the actual meaning?

```py
def get_values() -> list:
    query = "select value from table"
    result = db.execute(query)
    return [ value[0] for value in result ]
```

I think the `-> list` means this routine returns data type list
but I don't understand how the return (build a list)?
Why it is `value[0]`?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/ there you go.

Comment: ```return [ value[0] for value in result ]``` implies the variable result contains an iterable of lists/tuples from which you want to return the [0] element from each list/tuple in the iterable result.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" and similar mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i), [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sqlite3 (guessing) `execute()` returns a `<sqlite3.Cursor>` an iterable containing the tuples satisfying the conditions of your query.

Something like

```
('2006-01-05', 'BUY', 'RHAT', 100, 35.14)
('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.0)
('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.0)
('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.0)
...
```

Then

```
[value[0] for value in result]
```

creates a list of all the first columns in `result`.

```
['2006-01-05', '2006-03-28', '2006-04-06', '2006-04-05', ...]
```