# Don't understand the meaning of '->' in Python

Tags: python, function

I don't understand the meaning of `->` in Python. Searching gives me pages about bitwise operators, but there is no such operator among bitwise operators. It is usually used in a function's description.

Example:

```
class HelloOperator(BaseOperator):

    def __init__(
            self,
            name: str,
            **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Its called type hinting. See [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) link

Comment: See also: [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14379753/2745495)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `->` is not an operator.

`->` sort of defines what *return type* a function has. It is called a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Example:

```py
def foo(x) -> int:
  return x + 1
```

(whereas x should be an int, which you can also specify:

```py
def foo(x: int) -> int:
  return x + 1
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You have encountered [Type Hint](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), what is behind `->` inform what is type of thing returned by function, e.g.

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

means greeting function does return str.

When function or method does not have explicit return it do return `None`, hence `-> None` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

It's annotation. Programmers use them to show which type will be returned by function.

You can read more about it in the official documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html