# Vs Code + Python : What means VS (Pylance) autocomplete suggestion for get_success_url()

Tags: python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, pylance

When I define `get_success_url' in my views, if I accept Pylance Autocomplete suggestion, I got this :

```
def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        return super().get_success_url()
```

Didn't find anywhere how to use this.
By my side, I'm use to do :

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('name_space:url_name', kwargs={'pk': foo})
```

How to (can I) use pylance's suggestion to achieve the same result as my method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete version isn't actually doing anything.

Sometimes when you are overriding a function, you want to use the same function of the parent class plus something extra, eg, if you override save() you might set another property and then do a normal save, which you do by calling super().save().

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.status = Model.SAVED
    return super().save()
```

However, you don't always have to call super() if your function is doing the job on its own. In this case with the autocomplete, if all you do is `return super().get_success_url()`  there's no point in overriding the function as you haven't done anything different to an parent function. Your existing get_success_url() performs a purpose and replaces any super() version, so you don't need to call super() in it.

Autocomplete is just a suggestion, it's not saying you *need* to be doing something a certain way.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's clear. Last question : what about **`-> str:`**  Never saw/used this syntax.

Comment: There's a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions , but, in short, it's simply an annotation/documentation that says the function should return a string (though it doesn't enforce the function returning one, ie, it doesn't raise an error if it returns an int instead)